# I got failed to load on cloud scheduler page

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to create function has ability to refresh itself every 1 minute

but when I try write code below I got error on CMD

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

    exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 minutes').onRun((context) => {
      console.log('This will be run every 1 minutes!');
    });
```

*CMD when I write firebase deploy*

```
Error: HTTP Error: 400, Billing must be enabled for activation of service '[cloudscheduler.googleapis.com]' in project '45545844354(fake number)' to proceed.
```

When I visit [cloud scheduler](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudscheduler?project=fake-project) I got error message

```
Failed to load
```

About cloud scheduler , I should pay for this service and how much ?

I want only run 2 functions working everyday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is telling you that you need to have a billing method enabled for this project.  Please read the [documentation about scheduled functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) for more information.  It's clear that you need to be on the Blaze billing plan, and what the costs are.

Comment: I have able pay by paypal ?